# Do audio files impact the loading time of the website?

Tags: uploads, audio

I have to upload 10 audio files (sermons) on the WordPress website for my client, and these files are of around 70mbs explicitly. I need to know whether those audio files affect the loading time of the website or I have to compress them and put them on the website. I am afraid to lose the audio quality after compressing those audios.

thanks

Comment: This sounds like something you could test on your own very easily: make a speed check of the site without the audio files and compare it to the site with them.

Comment: If they preload when your page loads then yes. They will be render blocking the page. However, if you are displaying them with the audio tag, you can use preload attribute to prevent this. `<audio controls preload="none">`

Comment: @kero 
It will cost me so much time-consuming. Audios will take time to upload and after uploading if the website becomes heavy my all efforts will end in smoke. Please advice

Comment: @kero and Ovidiu 
what about uploading those audios on Sound Cloud? Will it work?